Converting GPS orthometric heights to height above MLLW
I need convert GPS elevation measurements collected along the coast of California to height above Mean Lower Low Water (MLLW) using NOAA's VDatum tool. The measurements were collected from 2010-2022 using a Trimble Pathfinder ProXRT, post-processed in Pathfinder Office, and exported as orthometric heights (above MSL) using Geoid03.
What I'm trying to understand is when converting these measurements in VDatum, are my heights actually in reference to NAVD88 (using Geoid03)?
Or in MSL?
Depending on latitude, the difference in the conversion to MLLW between NAVD88 (Geoid03) and MSL is ~0.8m.

My Trimble rep told me years ago that in TerraSync -> Settings -> Coordinate System that if the unit shows Mean Sea Level (MSL) the unit is actually referencing NAVD88.  This has been confirmed may times comparing the GNSS output values and available LiDAR that references NAVD88.
Of course, you need to ensure that the unit had Geoid03 set in the Geoid settings and not the default DMA 10x10(Global) setting.

Thank you! This is very helpful.

Your welcome.  I would appreciate it if you could mark the answer as accepted.
